# Parsley Validation for Select2 control

Tags: validation, jquery-select2, parsley.js

I am using Select2 control in HTML for multiple item selection.
All other controls on the forms are validation by parsley validator.
but `<select>` with select2 is not validating .so please guide me.
below is my code:
after assigning data:
on submit button click is as below:

```
   <select id="MultiDepartment" data-parsley-required="true" multiple="multiple" name="MultiDepartment"  class="multiple-select2 form-control"></select>
$('#MultiDepartment').select2({ placeholder: "Select Department" });
$("#demo-form").on('submit', function (e) {    
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this);

        form.parsley().validate();
        if (form.parsley().isValid()) {
            document.getElementById('UpComingLoader').style.display = "Block";
            SaveDataPerson();
        }
      });
```

Comment: There's probably a bad interaction between select2 & parsley? Please file an issue for Parsley, providing a live example and I'll take a look at it

Answer (score 1):

I created [a PR](https://github.com/select2/select2/pull/4649) to address this.

In the meantime the easiest is probably to trigger an `input` event manually:

```
$("#MultiDepartment").change(function() {
  $("#MultiDepartment").trigger('input')
})
```